# jquery mobile data-native-menu with data-history attribute

Tags: jquery-mobile

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <select data-mini="true" data-inline="false" data-history="false" data-native-menu="false" data-theme="d" data-overlay-theme="b" name="elArr[]">
        <option value="" data-placeholder="true">test</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Hi, I like use data-native-menu with data-histroy attribute same time. data-history property doesn't work. When opened native menu, it add hash ui-state=dialog to location bar.

Comment: data-history doesn't work. This property should disable hash adding